# Redux Dev Tool in Chrome throwing odd error

Tags: redux

When debugging my Redux store (running React) I keep getting this message

*apologies:"Serializing our large state kept crashing redux devtools. I hope to bring it back someday, but for now you can see the state by using `TS.redux.getState()` in the console"*

Has any one else seen this ?

And at the risk of being stupid I then run *TS.redux.getState()* in the console and get

> VM1468:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: TS is not defined
>       at :1:1

Any ideas why this is happening, besides what is said in the message.

As far as I'm aware I'm running to latest Chrome Add on v2.15.1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you're looking at the Slack `app store` and not your own Redux `store`.

If you are using Redux Dev Tools you can select which instance you are pointing to with the top right dropdown:

[image]